# What is the norm of this linear functional?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X = C[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions with the max norm. Then define the linear functional;

$$f(x) = \int_0^1 x(t)dt - x(1/2)$$

Then is the norm of this operator 1 or 0? I'm a little confused how to argue this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can cook up a continuous function with $x(0) = x(1) = 1$ and $x(\tfrac{1}{2}) = 0$ to convince yourself that it's not $0$. With that you may be able to give a good guess at what it then actually is.

Comment: Ok so it's definitely positive. How could I compute an upper bound?  Does there exist an x(t) such that $f(x)=1?$

Comment: Sure, you could take a function with $x(0) = x(1) = 1$, $x(\tfrac{1}{2}) = -1$ which decreases linearly on $(0,\tfrac{1}{2})$ and increases on $(\tfrac{1}{2},1)$. You may want to split your expression into the two summands and see how big each of them can become.

Comment: So is $f(x)$ unbounded then? Could you let $x(1/2) = -k$ and then as $k$ gets larger $f(x)$ just keeps increasing?

Comment: That would seem so, but remember that you have to divide by the norm of $x$ (which is $k$ in your example) when you calculate the norm of $f$. (That's why I only looked at norm $1$ examples of $x$.)

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer. The norm of this operator is equal to 2.

Explanation. Clearly the norm of this operator is less or equal to 2.

Set 
$$
x_n(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{llll}
1 & \text{if} & x\in[0,1/2-1/n], \\
n-1-2nt & \text{if} & x\in[1/2-1/n,1/2],\\
-n-1+2nt & \text{if} & x\in[1/2,1/2+1/n],\\
1 & \text{if} & x\in[1/2+1/n,1].
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then
$$
\|x_n\|=1,
$$
and
$$
\Big|\int_0^1 x_n(t)\,dt-x(1/2)\,\Big|\ge\int_0^{1/2-1/n}dt+\int_{1/2+1/n}^1dt
-\int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2+1/n}+1=2-\frac{4}{n}.
$$
Hence, the norm of this operator is greater or equal to $2-4/n$, for every $n\in\mathbb N$,
and hence, it is greater or equal to $2$.

Comment: Nice clear argument!